# Cannot generate access token in Exact Online API using POSTMAN

Tags: rest, exact-online

I have followed the Exact Online documentation to generate access token using authorization code using POST method as written in official documentation. 
Documentation link: [Get access token documentation](https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-oauth-eol-oauth-devstep3)
[image: Body Section]

But for some reason, the response to this request is invalid and cannot generate access token. What could be the possible solutions?

**Expected Outcome as per documentation:**
[image]

```json
{ code: "XTzM!IAAAACbPTzQJXwFhM"
, redirect_uri: ...
, grant_type: "authorization_code"
, client_id: "b81cc4de-d192-400e-bcb4-09254394c52a"
, client_secret: "n3G7KAhcv8OH"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the GET method instead of POST.

If that’s not working try to past the url with all the details present in the address bar of a browser. A form will be presented to you and fill in your username and password. After that take a careful look at the address bar. There you will find the token.

Btw why not use the implicit flow (use ‘token’ for grant_type). Access token is returned immediately.